# Calculate factorial of each value in a vector

Tags: r, vector, factorial

I am stuck trying to write a function that will calculate n! for each element of a vector without using if/then statements, the factorial function, or a loop.
I know cumprod can be used for this but can't get it to work.

```
#Code
x <- c(5, 2, 3, 8, 8, 1, 1, 7)
(y <-cumprod(x[i:1]))
```

Comment: Try this `sapply(x,factorial)`

Comment: Do you want a function with an input, let's say index `i`? Or do you want it in a one-shot approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try `factorial`

```
> factorial(x)
[1]   120     2     6 40320 40320     1     1  5040
```

or `gamma`

```
> gamma(x+1)
[1]   120     2     6 40320 40320     1     1  5040
```

or `mapply` + `prod`

```
> mapply(function(a,b) prod(a:b),1,x)
[1]   120     2     6 40320 40320     1     1  5040
```

Comment: Why is `Vectorize` necessary? Will this be faster than a plain `apply`?

Comment: @stephanmg Sorry, it doesn't need `Vectorize`, see my update.

Comment: Would it be faster with `Vectorize`? :)

Comment: @stephanmg I don't think so

Comment: By the way: Gamma function is defined somewhat along the lines: Gamma(n) = (n-1)! In case OP wonders why `x+1`.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Vectorize is basically a mapply wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

A way to avoid `factorial` and use `cumprod` is to loop over `x` and do the `cumprod` of the sequence of each value, i.e.

```
sapply(x, function(i) tail(cumprod(seq(i)), 1))
#[1]   120     2     6 40320 40320     1     1  5040
```

A couple of more options can be:

```
sapply(x, function(i) Reduce(`*`, seq(i)))
```

And as @jogo comments,

```
sapply(x, function(i) prod(seq(i)))
```

Comment: I think that OP wanted to use `cumprod`. So  this should be the accepted answer, if this is true. Maybe OP needs to clarify.

Comment: without cumprod(): `sapply(x, function(i) prod(seq(i)))`